# Find who has a reference to an object, to identify memory leak?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to trace down a memory leak in my tests.

Most of the guides for how to do this focus on "how to find the object(s) which are sticking around in memory".

I'm pretty sure I know which object is not being de-referenced. The problem I have is, **how do I find who has the reference to it, so I can clear it up?**

Is there a way in Chrome to inspect an object and see who still has a reference to it, at a point where I'm sure it should have been garbage-collected?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an expert here, but isn't setting a variable to `null` enough?

Comment: It would be enough if I knew who had the reference to set to `null` :) I know I can clear the reference that way, I just can't figure out who has the reference in the first place. It's an object that's passed around a fair bit and I'm worried the reference is living on in some closure somewhere.

Comment: That makes much more sense :P I have no idea on where to find where the problematic reference is, but good luck!